# Shell command to get color under mouse cursor (xorg)

Tags: shell, xorg

I need to get the color in hex code of the pixel beneath my mouse cursor. There are plenty fancy GUI-tools to solve this task, but I need a *simple* command line way to get the color, so that I can use the solution in a shell script.

Possibly I could use ImageMagick to take a (one pixel?) screenshot and extract the color from it (I can fetch the position using `xdotool`)). Maybe there is a simpler solution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not really satisfied with the other solution, I tried my ImageMagick idea. Works fine for me! (Depends on xclip, ImageMagick, xdotool, notify-send)

```
#!/bin/sh
# Get hex rgb color under mouse cursor, put it into clipboard and create a
# notification.

eval $(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)
IMAGE=`import -window root -depth 8 -crop 1x1+$X+$Y txt:-`
COLOR=`echo $IMAGE | grep -om1 '#\w\+'`
echo -n $COLOR | xclip -i -selection CLIPBOARD
notify-send "Color under mouse cursor: " $COLOR
```

**EDIT:**

Now using Gnome Shell, I have problems with the above solution (import won't take a screenshot of the visible windows, I don't know why. Hints are welcome). An alternative is to use a (fast) screenshot taker like `scrot` and use `convert` instead of `import`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Get hex rgb color under mouse cursor, put it into clipboard and create a
# notification.

scrot --overwrite /tmp/copycolor.png
eval $(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)
IMAGE=`convert /tmp/copycolor.png -depth 8 -crop 1x1+$X+$Y txt:-`
COLOR=`echo $IMAGE | grep -om1 '#\w\+'`
echo -n $COLOR | xclip -i -selection CLIPBOARD
notify-send "Color under mouse cursor: " $COLOR
```

**Update 2020:** Newer versions of scrot require the "--overwrite" option to be set for this to work.

Answer (score 7):

Sure you can. But you need another linux package. If you're on Ubuntu just issue:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool grabc
```

Then run grabc but background it

```
grabc &
```

Then perform a mouseclick using xdotool

```
xdotool click 1
```

The click will be captured by grabc's cursor and the background process will output the color.

But maybe it won't work from a script. For that purposes you might want to look at [this topic on the Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2155281).

Or if you don't mind, you can [do it with python as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605350/how-can-i-grab-the-color-of-a-pixel-on-my-desktop-linux).

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. grabc was almost the right tool, but this extra click is problematic. Using xdotool to click has timing issues. The python version was also nice, but a little bit slow.

Answer (score 4):

Another method to get the pixel color, based on @Christian's excellent answer:

```
eval $(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)
xwd -root -silent | convert xwd:- -depth 8 -crop "1x1+$X+$Y" txt:- | grep -om1 '#\w\+'
```

[`xwd`](http://www.xfree86.org/current/xwd.1.html) is significantly faster than `import` on my system.

Answer (score 2):

Fastest solution:

Edit/Update:

After reviewing new version of `https://github.com/muquit/grabc` I need to say that it beats anything else:

```
time ( COL=$(~/grabc/grabc -w $WINDOW_ID  -l +$X+$Y) ; echo COL=$COL )
COL=#2e2f30

real    0m0,006s
user    0m0,005s
sys     0m0,000s
```

Obviously this does not come with most of distros, so please use with caution. If you need something provided with your distro then old answer still stands:

```
time ( X=1 ; Y=1 ; xdotool mousemove --sync $X $Y sleep 0.01 click 1 \
       mousemove --sync restore & COL=$( grabc 2>/dev/null ) ; \
       echo COL=$COL )

COL=#ddedaa

real    0m0.046s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.008s
```

There can be timing issues - i.e. `sleep 0.01` part - but even increasing up to `0.1` it will be still faster than other solutions and you can detect error if `$COL` is empty.

If clicking is not an option, or timing issues are too problematic then I would probably go with import (then xwd then scrot if specific window shell makes problems)

Obviously for `$X` and `$Y` use `eval $(xdotool getmouselocation --shell)` or sth. similar

In comparison:

- **scrot**

  ```
    time ( X=1 ; Y=1 ; scrot /tmp/copycolor.png ; \
           IMAGE=$(convert /tmp/copycolor.png -depth 8 -crop 1x1+$X+$Y txt:- ) ; \
           COL=$( echo $IMAGE | grep -om1 '#\w\+' ) ; \
           echo COL=$COL )

    COL=#DDEDAA

    real    0m0.590s
    user    0m0.596s
    sys     0m0.024s
  ```
- **xwd**

  ```
    time ( X=1 ; Y=1 ; COL=$( xwd -root -silent | \
          convert xwd:- -depth 8 -crop "1x1+$X+$Y" txt:- | grep -om1 '#\w\+' ) ; \
          echo COL=$COL )

    COL=#DDEDAA

    real    0m0.387s
    user    0m0.380s
    sys     0m0.084s
  ```
- **import:**

  ```
    time ( X=1 ; Y=1 ; IMAGE=$(import -window root -depth 8 -crop 1x1+$X+$Y txt:-) ;\
          COL=$( echo $IMAGE | grep -om1 '#\w\+' ) ; \
          echo COL=$COL )

    COL=#DDEDAA

    real    0m0.302s
    user    0m0.456s
    sys     0m0.044s
  ```

Comment: For me, I use `picom` to have semitransparent windows, and I've found (unexpectedly but happily) that this `grabc` thing is not affected by it.

Comment: @Enlico - thanks for info. I've just updated an answer because I've started to use new version of grabc - it's really fast and works well inside scripts