# How to get the value of a pixel from the screen (GTK 3, Shell, Linux)

Tags: linux, shell, x11, gtk3

I am trying to do some automation on Linux, and I can't find a good way to get a pixel value from the screen, given 2 coordinates.

I have this python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pyautogui
import sys

image = pyautogui.screenshot()
print(str(image.getpixel((int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2])))))
```

How can I do this without taking a screenshot and instead read from the pixel buffer?

If there is a program that someone knows about that can do this (I've heard AutoHotkey on windows can), that would also be helpful, as I'm using **shell** script (and lots of `xdotool`) to do the automation.

Comment: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Color_of_a_screen_pixel#Python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I grab the color of a pixel on my desktop? (Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605350/how-can-i-grab-the-color-of-a-pixel-on-my-desktop-linux)

Comment: you have multiple solutions there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1605380/632926

Comment: @gabrielstuff thanks, that led me to my eventual solution. The things on that page needed to be re-written for gtk3, but that got me close enough that I could do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code, when called like this: `./getColor.py [X coordinate] [Y coordinate]`, will print the decimal RGB color value of the specified pixel on the screen in the form `(R, G, B)`

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import gi, sys
gi.require_version('Gdk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gdk
pixbuf = Gdk.pixbuf_get_from_window(Gdk.get_default_root_window(), int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]), 1, 1)
print(tuple(pixbuf.get_pixels()))
```